# C# console app System.StackOverflowException' was thrown on big list/array

Tags: c#, console

I trying to write a simple console app for a friend that want to use it for lottery. The app is working fine on small list but as the list grows, it became slower and finally it throws overflow exception. When the list length is less than 5.000, it works fine.

The app asks for starting ticket number, ending ticket number and winning numbers. Then it takes rnadom numbers of the list and delete them so no dublicates occur.

As i understand, the problem is not the length of the list, but the method that select the number from the list and removes right after.

[image]

You can see the code here:
[dotnetfiddle script](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZH2p8l)

The console app is compiled with .net 4.8

Comment: Why are you using recursion for this operation in the first place?  A call stack that's *5000 calls deep* certainly doesn't sound great.  What is this method *meant* to accomplish?

Comment: Additionally... Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop instead of recursion, and only call `.ToList()` once for the array

```
public static int GetNumber(int[] arr) 
{
    return GetNumber(arr.ToList());
}
public static int GetNumber(List<int> list)
{
    while (list.Count > 1)
    {
        //Remove random number from list
        list.RemoveAt(random.Next(0, list.Count));
    }

    return list[0];
}
```

Though, if I understood what you are trying to accoplish you could just do this instead

```
//create a hashSet as this type can only contain unique entries
HashSet<int> selectedNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWinningTickets; i++)
{
    while(true)
    {
        //+ 1 because the upperBound is exclusive    
        var r = random.Next(startingNumber, endingNumber + 1);

        var added = selectedNumbers.Add(r);

        //added will be TRUE if a unique number got added to SelectedNumbers
        if (added == true)
            break;
    }
}
```

See an example:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/q6kAUp

Comment: wow. I am impresed of how much cleaner it is and how much faster it runs even on 15.000 list items. I am not a programmer as occupation rather as hobby. i don't beleive i would have though it like this.

Comment: @AthanasopoulosEpameinontasAn - have a look at my edit

Comment: The first example works better for me when i must have ranges of tickets that have breaks between them (1-200, 250-300, 310-1000, rest not used). In case of fixed range the second example seems better.